# Pivot Grid in Extjs 4

Tags: extjs

How can we Implement Pivot Grid in Extjs 4.

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, the PivotGrid will probably be officially slated for 4.1. It may or may not be included in the compatibility layer, that's not yet certain. Basically I would not count on jumping on 4.0 on day one if pivot grid is critical to your app.  This may change, but I'm just going off of the status as of today.

Answer (score 1):

You can find pivot grid examples here:  [Pivot Grid Examples (Ext 3.3)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/#sample-3)

Comment: Actually, it is not for Extjs 4. I have aleardy used this in Ver. Extjs 3.3. But, Now I need to implement it on Extjs 3 to 4 Conversion.

Comment: I see your problem its probably worth asking on the Ext forum. Although your question has been asked there already. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?129356-Pivot-Grid-in-Extjs-4.&p=588568

Comment: JS Compatibility Layer

This is an optional JavaScript file that can be referenced after Ext 4 is loaded that will provide the aliases and overrides necessary to make the vast majority of Ext 3 code run correctly under Ext 4 as-is.

NOTE: At the moment this compatibility layer is not yet available, but it will be prior to the final 4.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a PivotGrid for Extjs 4.1.x. 
You can see the [pivot grid examples here](http://www.mzsolutions.eu/mzPivotGrid.html) and checkout the [documentation](http://www.mzsolutions.eu/docs/).

Here are some core features:

- Multiple aggregators with different aggregate functions
- Sort and name the dimension axis
- Sort columns
- Lock left axis columns or not
- Group aggregated rows/cols and expand or collapse the groups
- Summarize group rows and group columns
- Grand total for rows and columns
- Supported aggregation functions: sum, avg, min, max, count and group% (calculates the percentage from the group total)
- drill down plugin

Comment: Both link goes to the same page, at least, the same *renderer* page. Could you fix them?